Measure ± 1V Differential DC using ADS1115
I'm trying to measure a differential DC voltage range of -1V to 1V using an ADS1115 connected to an ESP32. I’ve implemented a voltage divider circuit based on a design suggested by Joseph W in this TI forum post. The circuit uses an LM358 op-amp to create a virtual ground at 2.5V, and the ADS1115, ESP32, and op-amp are all powered with a 5V supply.
I expected to see readings close to my input voltages, but the actual readings are significantly lower. Here are some sample measurements I took with different input voltages:



Input Voltage
ADS1115 Reading




1.025 V
0.610 V


727 mV
0.430 V


627 mV
0.370 V


523 mV
0.307 V


424 mV
0.250 V


328 mV
0.193 V


223 mV
0.130 V


126 mV
0.070 V



Why are the readings lower than expected?
Is there an adjustment I need to make, or am I missing something in the setup?

I measuring the differential voltage between Copper sulphate half cell and reinforced steel in concrete where i connect my negative terminal of the multimeter to half-cell and positive terminal to the rebar. I am supplying 5V to my whole system (ESP32, Op-amp, ADC) using my power supply.

What is the common mode voltage of the differential signal?

I am sorry it might sound dumb but could you specify between what points you want the voltage value

Why haven't you used a differential amplifier? The circuit you have used is rubbish for your apparent application.

Probably! And I am certainly not deferring to make any changes. Could you perhaps guide me with a better circuit @Andyaka

You need to describe exactly the characteristics of your source.

@Andyaka I measuring the differential voltage between Copper sulphate half cell and reinforced steel in concrete. I am supplying 5V to my whole system (ESP32, Op-amp, ADC) using my power supply.

@neospice Common-mode voltage is the voltage from either of the pins (CN1 pins 1 and 2) towards ground. It could also be checked after the input resistors, at the ADS1115 pins for A0 and A1 (pins 7 and 8), though they will differ by the amount of difference between resistors. You should include ALL of your measured voltages in your question, and mention what did you use them with. Maybe include a part of your code meant for input range and calibration.

@neospice Were you measuring those voltages at the cell with a digital voltmeter while your ADC circuit was disconnected? Please include more details in your question if you want it answered successfully!

@EdinFifić My ADC circuit was connected to the whole time with my voltmeter attached along side. I was measuring the voltage between half-cell and concrete rebar which is my input with my voltmeter and connected my ADC as described in the circuit diagram.

@neospice I have added my long-time prepared answer (I have been busy). Let me know if it helps you.

You have not given all the details that could help us, but so far it is clear that you want to measure the voltage from a half-cell method for testing concrete rebar health and you probably want to store or transfer the measurement data using an MCU.
For simplicity, I will refer to the whole half-cell, concrete and rebar combination as a "cell".
The first problem I see with your input is its relatively low input impedance which significantly reduces the voltage from the cell.
According to this page (https://www.humboldtmfg.com/blog/perform-report-half-cell-corrosion-mapping) the required minimum resolution is 10mV and input impedance 10MΩ, which is what most digital voltmeters have.
The ADS1115 datasheet from TI shows that its input impedance is significantly higher at higher FSR (full-scale range).

The highest FSR setting will give you a whopping 22MΩ input impedance, and you still get better than 1mV resolution; it is actually less than 0.2mV.
However, your bigger problem is your input voltage divider, which not only halves the input voltage, but also overloads the cell and further reduces its voltage.
Below is a schematic which shows that the cell voltage is exactly half when the voltage source can supply enough current, and we assume cell impedance to be practically zero.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In reality, the cell has probably up to about 10kΩ impedance, which further reduces its voltage at the ADC input.
Adding a half-voltage (center-point) bias does not change the voltage drop across resistors.

simulate this circuit
On page 32 of the datasheet, it is mentioned that protection diodes are added on the inputs towards supply rails, meaning they don't allow voltages to go exceed 0.3V above or below the rails:

10.1.3 Input Protection
The ADS111x are fabricated in a small-geometry, low-voltage process. The analog inputs feature
protection diodes to the supply rails. However, the current-handling
ability of these diodes is limited, and the ADS111x can be permanently
damaged by analog input voltages that exceed approximately 300 mV
beyond the rails for extended periods. One way to protect against
overvoltage is to place current-limiting resistors on the input lines.
The ADS111x analog inputs can withstand continuous currents as large
as 10 mA.

Knowing the above details, it is easy to calculate that the input common-mode (across both ADC inputs, relative to negative supply) voltage can reach as high as 100V with 10kΩ input resistors on each side without damaging the ADC.
Now, the final schematic with all of the above information and increased bias resistor values:

simulate this circuit
As you can see, the voltage drop is less than 1% across the internal impedance of the cell and the input current-limiting resistors when the bias resistor values are increased to 2.2MΩ.
You can actually increase the bias resistors up to 22MΩ or more without losing accuracy because the differential voltage will be the same as long as the negative side doesn't go below 0V relative to negative ADC power supply rail.
Either way, I would recommend bias resistor values of at least 1MΩ.
Because of the large resistances and impedances involved, and especially because of the differential measurement method, your mid-point voltage bias does not have to be sturdy; all it has to ensure is that the negative side doesn't go below 0V of the supply rail under the full range of input voltages (which is narrow in your case).
With high input impedance and resistor values, it is easy to get significant noise on the input, and this noise can easily be reduced with a simple capacitor across ADC inputs.
Below is a FINAL practical schematic for your circuit:

simulate this circuit

Will this setup achieve 10MΩ impedance and <10pA current? I’m planning to use 3 ADS1115s, each with 4 inputs, connecting three inputs to half-cells and one to rebar to measure differential voltage between each half-cell and rebar. This setup allows me to monitor multiple points on the concrete surface simultaneously. For each half-cell input, I’ll use 10k/2.2M dividers and 100nF capacitors between rebar and half-cell. Are there any additional requirements for stability or accuracy and will the same setup work with my additional requirement?

@neospice Not really 10MΩ but still high enough to keep the voltage drop below 1%. You can achieve over 10MΩ input resistance if you make the R2 and R4 10MΩ each. In that case you will have about 2mV or about 0.2% voltage drop, which should be totally acceptable and more than enough accuracy. I don't see why the current needs to be <10pA. The concrete rebar health measurements are neither that precise nor do they need that much precision. As far as I know, 1mV accuracy is far more than needed. There are much greater errors from the measurement technique itself.

Wont the 10MΩ resistors induce much higher noise. Will the existing 0.1uF capacitor be sufficient. Also, what about the 9 half cells that I talked about in the comment. Any take on that?

@neospice I think it will work and will be sufficient. You can check your measurements against a standard voltmeter before you connect your ADC circuit, just remember typical DVM stated accuracy is about 0.5%. Either way, since these are DC measurements, you should able to easily verify them with a good DVM. Just try it out and see how it works. I would like to hear back from you about the results.

Sure thing. I am sending this to fabrication. Lets hope for the best

The 10kΩ resistors form voltage dividers, so I would expect half the input voltage to appear at the ADS1115 inputs. Here is essentially what you have for the first input voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With a 1.025V input you have a differential voltage of 512.5mV at the ADS1115.
I'm not sure why you are getting a higher than expected reading- I suggest measuring the actual voltages at the inputs (both common-mode and differential) and checking the code if the voltages appear to be similar to those on the above schematic. The ratio of resistor values is important- any error or drift in the resistors relative to each other will result in an error in the reading- so they should be precision types to get the most out of the chip accuracy. If some of the resistors were actually the wrong value that could help explain the discrepancy. R5 and R6 are not as important for differential measurements. This circuit will also put Vdd noise on the inputs so it might be prudent to bypass the non-inverting input of the LM358 with a capacitor to analog ground.

Possible alternative:
This biases the low side of your input by +2.5V relative to circuit ground. Without detailed knowledge of the source, and what all your circuit is connected to it's difficult to evaluate if that's actually practical, so it is left to you for now to think about whether there are sneak paths such as USB ports or other connections that force some relationship between the ground and input. 2.5V is more than enough to cause electrolytic action if such is possible.

simulate this circuit

Is there any way I can get accuracy without the need of calibration and just use simple math or something like that in code as scaling factor or multiplier. Is there a different approach that could result in much better and robust results

Depends on your error budget and what exactly the input consists of. You can buy precision resistors and plop them down. 0.1% resistors are not too expensive. Even 0.01% resistors are < $1 in q 100 these days. But this circuit puts current through the input source- if it's not a perfect voltage source there will be errors on that account֫- the reading may accurately reflect the input voltage, but the input voltage will be different from what it would be without the measuring circuit attached.

I measuring the differential voltage between Copper sulphate half cell and reinforced steel in concrete. I am supplying 5V to my whole system (ESP32, Op-amp, ADC) using my power supply.

Can't you just bias one side of the half-cell relative to your ground by 2.5V and go directly into the ADC (ignoring any protection and filtering for now)?  That would not affect the accuracy at all, no precision components or calibration required.

Please correct me if I am wrong. You suggest that I remove the Opamp and connect the voltage divider's output directly at the place where the the Opamp's output was connected. Is this correct?

@neospice See the edit for one possibility (resistor precision is unimportant, within reason), but note my comments about grounds. A more complex alternative would be to generate a negative voltage (say -5V) and use op-amps or an in-amp to shift the input into the input range of the ADC- that would allow the grounds to be at the same potential and have the inputs high impedance.

the half cell that I am talking about will act as the Anode, and the concrete will act as an anode. So how should the connections be in this scenario considering the circuit that you just edited? To understand more about what I am trying to measure you can refer the image here: https://www.giatecscientific.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Figure2.jpg

What is the electrical relationship of your circuit ground to the rebar potential?

The circuit ground serves as the 0V reference for my electronics, but it’s not directly related to the rebar’s potential. In this setup, I’m using a copper sulfate half-cell as a stable reference to measure the potential difference between the half-cell and the rebar. This measurement is then biased to 2.5V (relative to ground) to bring it into the input range of my ADC.

Sorry, this has strayed too far from the original question and I don't see an obvious response without getting deeper. But I don't think you want the original circuit because it loads the input with 20kΩ, even if the bias ends up acceptable. Suggest a new question may be in order.

The R1/R2 and R3/R4 are attenuating the differential voltage by 50%. That's why your readings are off by half.
Easy fix: change the ADS1115 PGA settings to a range of +/-512mV. Done.
I'm not sure what the allowable input impedance can be. Your circuit has 10k. I suspect it may need to be higher than that.
I suggest adding a pair of follower op-amps on your inputs, or consider using a diff in/diff out buffer.
Maybe something like this (simulate it here):

This is a bastardized instrumentation amplifier with a common-mode bias of 2.5V. Note that this assumes that the instrument is floating (that is, battery operated.) If it isn't, you will need to consider a galvanically isolated buffer.
The Gain Adjust resistor compensates for the non-ideal op-amp gain (in the sim, set to 100k.) You could consider using more gain and a lower PGA full-scale setting.
I'm sure there's more than this that I'm missing for this sensitive instrument, but this should work.

Because I was curious, I looked this up. This half-cell test methodology is used to measure rebar corrosion in reinforced concrete. More here: https://www.giatecscientific.com/education/what-is-the-half-cell-potential-test/
The short take: the test measures the voltage developed between the half-cell placed at the concrete surface and an exposed piece of rebar. Voltages in the hundreds of millivolts, precision required is about 3 significant figures.

MORE
The thing I was missing is the required input impedance for the half-cell, 10M ohms. This led me to rethink the design somewhat, and I came up with this (simulate it here):

The 'rebar' side is treated as low impedance and forms the reference - it's constrained to nearly ground.
The 'half-cell' side is high impedance. Since it goes negative, the op-amp requires a negative supply too (I'm assuming +/-5V supplies.) This might even want a driven (guard) shield, which can be taken from the op-amp (-) input.
Gain is +2 on both sides. The output is both attenuated and re-biased to 2.5V in one go, then on it goes to the ADC.

That's really a wonderful approach and I believe it's better than mine. What should be the precision of the resistors in the attached circuit? Is it necessary that all the resistors are MFR? Also I am able to get positive results from my own circuit itself however I was wondering is there anything wrong in my approach as well?

After I looked into what is involved in this testing, I had some concern that your bias network will be loading the half-cell too much. The resistors would need to be carefully matched. Also, you have no input protection.

My approach is not as sensitive, since the buffers are nearly unity gain. Almost no current flows though the feedback.

Have a look at this doc: https://www.rilem.net/images/publis/1218.pdf, sec. 6.1.1. They recommend a voltmeter with a minimum impedance of 10M ohm. So even my proposal needs work.

That's a really informative doc right there. They indeed recommend a minimum impedance of 10M ohm and your approach draws almost no current compared to the doc you shared where the say that the current should not exceed from 10pA. However is it really necessary to take these steps into account if I compare the accuracy that I need which is of ±1mV and even ±5mV would do. Moreover the ADS1115 has a very high input impedance in itself.

I think it makes sense to treat the voltage as single-ended. Make the rebar system ground, then run the half-cell to a single high impedance buffer that's offset to midpoint. The ADS1115 supports single-ended operation.

In my experience with ADCs they kick back a fair amount of noise with their sample-and-hold activity and need buffering.

I saw the revised design that you shared. Is it possible to achieve the output wothout using negative supply. Moreover what diode and opamp do you reccomend for this circuit. in your last comment you mentioned that i should do single endded measurement. could you explain how should i make the rebar system ground and then measure the adc in single ended mode

Will TL072 as op-amp and BAT54 for diode work?

As I recall the TL072 has a fairly high voltage rail requirement. Look for a newer type that operates at lower voltage and swings rail to rail. For the input protection a 1N4148 is ok.

Thanks a lot for the help. Just one last thing. How should I connect 9 half cells to cover a larger area where the rebar is common. also will MCP6002 do?

Since the ADS1115 can handle 2 diff channels, you'd need 5 of them. ADS1115 can only support 4 selectable I2C addresses, so you will need to have a second I2C bus from your ESP32. That shouldn't be too big of a deal I think. For the op-amp I'd look at the AD823 or maybe the CMOS OPA2342.

Since the Rebar is common, cant I do differential measurement where out of the 4 pins of ads1115 I connect one pin to rebar and rest of the three pins with half cell. With this I would only need 3 ADCs. I tested this setup with my power supply where I measured the voltages and it was working. My only question is how will the opamps setup change in this configuration. I was hoping I could use some quad channel opamp and with that I would only need 3 opamp ic

The probe impedance requirement is stringent enough that I think each input deserves its own buffer. What you can do is make each channel be a separate +2 gain (use two 1k to GND instead of 2k between them.) Route the half-cell amps through an analog mux, then to the attenuation/shift resistors.

Two 4:1 selectors can support 8 half-cells. The rebar ref can be shared since it’s buffered.

could you please provide a diagram of what you just said

Let's call the nodes where A0 and A1 are connected \$V_+\$ and \$V_-\$ respectively and let's consider \$R1=R3\$ and \$R2=R4\$.
Performing nodal analysis at points \$V_+\$ and \$V_-\$ we have:
\$(V_+-2.5V)/R1+(V_+-V1)/R2=0\$;
\$(V_--2.5V)/R1+(V_--V2)/R2=0\$;
Subtracting the first equation from the second gives us:
\$V_+-V_-=(V1-V2)*R1/(R1+R2)\$, where \$V1-V2\$ is the differential voltage
When \$R1\$ is equal to \$R2\$ we get \$V_+-V_- = V_{diff}/2\$. The values in your table are a little higher, probably because of the resistance of pins A0 and A1. What I would recommend you do is put buffers on the inputs of A0 and A1 to get exactly \$V_{diff}/2\$ and in your code treat this division by 2 by multiplying the reading by 2.
It would look something like this:

Where \$R7\$ and \$R8\$ would be the resistors of pins A0 and A1

With this will I be able to achieve an accuracy of ± 1mV. Also is it really the issue of the resistance of A0 and A1 pins previously when working with only positive differential voltages I was not connecting any buffer circuit and was still getting accurate results. Now I am using this 2.5V bias as I want to measure the range of ± 1V.

Let's do the math:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Calculate \$V_X\$ as a function of input \$V_A\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X &= 2.5 + (V_A-2.5) \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
&= 2.5 + \frac{1}{2} (V_A - 2.5) \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2}V_A + 1.25
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly for \$V_Y\$:
$$ V_Y = \frac{1}{2}V_B + 1.25 $$
Your ADC is measuring the difference \$V_X-V_Y\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X - V_Y &= \left( \frac{1}{2}V_A + 1.25 \right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}V_B + 1.25 \right) \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2}V_A - \frac{1}{2}V_B + 1.25 -1.25 \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(V_A - V_B) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Here's a table of values I'd expect from the ADC, using that expression, together with your own results, and the error:



\$V_A - V_B\$ (mV)
\$V_X - V_Y\$ (mV)
Measured (mV)
Error (%)




1025
513
610
+19


727
364
430
+18


627
314
370
+18


523
262
307
+17


424
212
250
+18


328
164
193
+18


223
112
130
+16


126
63
70
+11



You haven't told us how you derived or measured the potential difference  \$V_A-V_B\$ during testing. I'm assuming that last outlier is an error in measurement, since everything else has a consistent +18% error. You are trying to identify where that systematic 18% error comes from.
Assuming the resistors are all 5% or 1%, they are unlikely to be the problem, but you should measure them anyway, just to be sure.
The expression for \$V_X-V_Y\$ doesn't mention the 2.5V offset, it's independent of that, so that's not the problem either.
The gain of the ADS1115 is ±2.048V can be configured. For instance, if you set FSR to ±2.048V, that would  correspond to ±32768 conversion result (I believe; I didn't read the datasheet fully). Are you scaling the digital conversion result correctly? For \$V_A-V_B=1.025V\$, which produces \$V_X-V_Y=513mV\$ I would expect a reading of \$\frac{0.513}{2.048}\times 32768 = 8208\$.
There are two other possible sources of error that I can see here, both involving the source of \$V_A-V_B\$. Either you measured it wrong (70mV is hard to measure accurately with a cheap multimeter), or that source of potential difference has significant output impedance.
My money is on the latter. If whatever you are using to produce \$V_A-V_B\$ has an output impedance comparable with 18% of R1 (or maybe R1+R2, I didn't do the math), that would produce a systematic error near 18%.
If I were you, my next test wouldn't be to measure \$V_A-V_B\$, I would measure \$V_X-V_Y\$, using a good quality, high-impedance digital voltmeter, to see if that corresponds to my ADC's readings. At least then I could rule out the ADC as the problem.

I realized that I need a fairly high impedance of 10M Ohm and the current should not exceed 10pA so I don't think my approach is going to work anymore and I would rather need to implement buffers at each stage with high input impedance
